# How to forward arguments to a super function in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm a very perl beginner, but I have (more or less) this code:

```
package Base;

sub foo{
  my ($self, $first, $second, $third) = @_;
  # do some magic here!
} 

package Subclass;
use base qw(Base);

sub foo{
  my ($self, $first, $second, $third) = @_;
  #do something with $first only
  return $self->SUPER::foo($first, $second, $third);
}
```

And the method is called with: `$self->foo("Hey", "what's", "up");`

Is there a more concise way to call `SUPER::foo()`, without repeating the list of all args again?

Comment: `shift->SUPER::foo(@_)` Consider `parent` instead of `base` as former is recommended for inheritance.

Comment: @Сухой27, That relies on undefined operand evaluation order. That said, many people rely on this as well, so it's unlikely to change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can re-use `@_` to pass the arguments like this

```
$self->SUPER::foo(@_);
```

Since the first element of `@_` is the "object" used to call the class method, you don't want to pass that into the parent class method twice, so you should use `shift` to remove it first.

```
sub foo{
  my $self=shift;
  my ($first, $second, $third) = @_;
  #do something with $first only
  return $self->SUPER::foo(@_);
}
```

Comment: Since @justHelloWorld asked for conciseness, we can do something with $first only like this: $_[0] = 'new_first'  This is after $self has already been shifted in the line before...

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be one of the valid uses of the `&function;` call.

E.g.

```
&SUPER::foo;
```

As documented in [perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) - this makes `@_` visible to the called sub.

It should be used with care, because it's deviating from what you might normally expect to happen - it's not passing args, it's making the same set 'visible'.

Comment: `&SUPER::foo` doesn't work as you expect. Because it's not a method call, `SUPER` isn't special, so this calls sub `foo` in package `SUPER`. The class's parent is not consulted. You'd have to use `&Base::foo`.